# Camunda - external connector for BPMN - CMMN - DMN with list of data incoming?

Tags: camunda

Its just a wildcard question, I am new here in Camunda. Before I start the process flow, thought of clarifying something

From the experience working with BonitaSoft - we can write our on connectors.
Is that possible, to extend the apis to customize the functionality ?

I am not understanding the CMMN, is there any Case Management storyboard/usecase available in realtime?

Can we customize the views only, with clients like Angular-JS/2 ?

Any guidance will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can write own connectors, see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/process-engine/connectors/. However, in our best-practices we advise to prefer "normal" Java Delegates with Field Injection over Connectors unless you have a very good reason to write connectors.

What do you mean with Case Management Storyboard? There is a get started guide available: https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/cmmn11/. There will be also a third edition of the "REal-Life BPMN" book released this week, which has a description of CMMN including more real-life examples.

I do not understand the question about customization from the dscription above. You can implement your own User Interface in whatever language/framework you like on top of the Camunda API. Maybe that's what you are asking?

Comment: about case-management, I wish to know on real life examples, from one of your lecture on the same what I have understood is, complex gateways can be replaced with cmmn. Regarding UI, are all the functionalities available as Camunda RestApis so that I can use my own UI technologies?

Comment: are those the connectors to connect with the camunda-engines looks like one, the connectors I was talking about is, lets say if I have to use externalApis(web-service) for example a content management system. How could I extend the camudna tasks?

Comment: is it good to implement JavaDelegate to call our own connectors, for example can we call a new service which is custom written to connect to a MessageQueue?